# How to undelete only the audio files that might have got deleted earlier?

Tags: data-recovery

Today I got upset to see that a few audio files (all under one directory) that were there in my Ubuntu 15.10 system were missing. So, as my system was sometimes used by another person, I suppose it was intentionally deleted by him. It might be deleted any time within last couple of months. Now how to recover it?

I'd not been using my laptop much and didn't download anything in last 2 months. Ya but once I'd updated the system with 250 MB data using `Software Updater`.

I'd earlier used `photorec` successfully and I'm aware of a few other recovery tools like `testdisk, extundelete`. In my experience, `photorec` doesn't undelete on specific file types like audio, video, etc. So, I want to know if any way is there so that rather than undeleting all recoverable files consuming many GBs of disk space, I can undelete only audio files which will take away the burden of providing a big recoverable space to the tool? I googled but didn't find any way to undelete based on specific file type.

I would like to add that I don't know anything about the deleted file names and the extensions. Simply I know they are audio files.

I would prefer apart from answering that caters to my need, you can please extend it by adding informations on how to undelete any files of any specific file types like audio, video, text, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Photorec should work.  You will have to specify the specific format(s) you want though, you can't just say "audio".

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step#Selection_of_files_to_recover